# The dragonfly diet

Tags: science-based, biology, zoology

So basically what I want to know what dietary changes to human would need to happen to support this human dragonfly 
-Chitin claws on all fingers and toes; and three chitin spikes on each limb

- 9-10 meter long dragonfly wings

-2 meter long dragonfly tail with enlarged pincers

-enlarged  retractable dragonfly mandibles that can cut through steel

-faster processing speed of the mind equal to that of a dragonfly

other than the the rest is normal human biology

Comment: Human biochemistry cant support those things, human biochemistry is barely able to support transplants of organs from another human without a massive cocktail of heavy immune suppressants and various specialized steroids. Modifying an organism is not copy and pasting body-parts. such a practice will result in the body's immune system attacking itself, or horrible fast growing uncontrollable tumors.

Comment: @TCAT117 I never said that the biochemistry was human, this hybrid has been like this since he was a zygote

Comment: That zygote would auto-abort itself. no joke. Its the whole reason you cant make a centaur by falling in love with a horse.

Comment: @TCAT117 well crap, better handwave that into the corner over there...

Comment: @TCAT117 you sure Crisper couldn’t solve it?

Comment: No, you can add whatever DNA you want to any other bit of DNA but that doesn't mean the organism can survive past the first cell division. The most you could do using real science is grow a really really weird cyst in a petri dish. To make this work you would need near magical levels of understanding in nano-machines so you could have them inside the organism both to fabricate the foreign organic tissue and to maintain it without rejection and crippling fast burning cancers. At that point why even bother with the dragonfly thing, since you've now basically created a living god.

Comment: @TCAT117 well ignoring that glaring fact what diet would he need

Comment: when you invent intelligent self replicating nano-bots capable of colonizing and modifying a human body you let me know.

Comment: the mandibles even if reinforced and scaling up from the mandibles of a normal dragonfly, cutting through steel would be difficult and most likely damage the mandibles. Also, dragonflies just eat other insects, so his diet should be, insects, alot of it.

Comment: @MatthewNg you got a point, I may do with titan beetle mandible, also what could the dragonfly mandibles break through

Comment: `faster processing speed of the mind equal to that of a dragonfly` I would love to know where you got this idea from.

Comment: @Renan I read it some where but I can't remember

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitin

> **Chitin** (C<sub>8</sub>HO<sub>5</sub>N)n (/ˈkaɪtɪn/ KY-tin), a long-chain polymer of N-acetylglucosamine, **is a derivative of glucose**.

IOW, there's nothing in chitin that we don't already eat every day.

Thus, what would need to change isn't the diet, but the human's **complete biochemistry**.

Maybe as the result of an eccentric scientist working on a teleporter who has an accident when a dragonfly inadvertently [flies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091064/) into the teleporter with the scientist during a test.

Comment: But would you need to eat more to support these formations???

Comment: With a larger body, and expending more energy... sure you'll need to eat more.  But "eating more because you're (a lot) more active" isn't really a dietary change.

Answer (score 1):

Your human dragonfly would need to alter the bony moorings of the existing skeleton to support wings/tails/mandibles.  These are all long, strongly moving appendages which would exert a lot of leverage onto their skeletal attachment points which would need to be robust.

I will assume all materials are made of tissues already within the human repertoire.

As regards diet, diet is at essence the intake of materials needed to support energetic expenditures and maintenance/regeneration of the body (or new bodies in the case of reproduction).  We do both things already with our diet.  Flight might be energetically very expensive and so your human dragonfly would need more calorically dense materials.  Antarctic explorers eat butter to increase caloric intake.  I would expect your human dragonfly would have a penchant for eating fats and oils which are the most calorically dense materials in our diet.

I am little concerned that nothing in the human physiologic repertoire offers the hardness needed to cut through steel as the mandibles do.  Teeth are the hardest thing we have and I do not think they would withstand the pressure needed.  You would need some new biochemistry to allow these humans to make some hard crystalline material equal to the task.  Alternatively, these are humans, and so they could augment ther biological forms with artificial addons - perhaps sapphire crowns or sheaths that harden the mandibles to steel-cutting hardness.

Answer (score 0):

Can't happen. Firstly a dragonfly has an exoskeleton and a human an endoskeleton.

[Exoskeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exoskeleton) creatures are limited in size due to issues with growing and molting shells

Next issue is the wings. Larger flying animals need bones to maintain the strength of the wing as where insects inflate their wings.

Human bones are extremely strong but pay for this in bone density as where birds have much lighter honeycomb bones

Basically to sum it up, to make such a creature, you wouldn't use human or dragonfly DNA. I doubt you could even use DNA. The creature would have to be completely manufactured. 9 meter dragonfly like wings would have to be a graphene and carbon nanotube structure and the muscles to drive such wings don't exist in nature.

Comment: I appreciate the time you put into this answer but being super scientiically accurate isn't my goal, I'm really just going for medium science fiction. Also their are other extinct birds that weighed as much as a human that had a wingspan of 24 meters, yes your right birds are different and if an actual biologist were to look at it they would declare it as inaccurate, but it's a fictional dude in a fictional world, plus none of this is set in stone if you have any recamendations I would gladly change up some of the biology, but the main thing I want hard science on is the diet